# Using an new attribute for the product name Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

In my grouped products I Need the Title of my products to be shorter so I have made a custom attribute with the attribute code table_name (label: Table_name).

I found this is the line of code which generates the name that is displayed in the table

```
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
```

So, I thought just changing this would get the job done as I have below

```
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getTable_name()) ?></td>
```

When I var_dump the products I can see the table name is displayed in the products like

```
["short_name"]=> string(11) "Extra Small"
```

So I know the attribute is being called but how do I pull the short now out of the product to display?

But no luck. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the attribute table_name to display instead of the attribute Name?

Thank you

Comment: `getName()` is a magento core method, but for custom attribute use `getAttributeText('attribute_code')` to get the value for the attribute

Comment: I tried <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('table_name')) ?></td> But that didnt work or am i being stupid and i need to change "AttributeText"

Comment: have you set the attribute option `visible on Frontend` to `yes`.Check by logging the item and search with whether your attribute comes with product model.

Comment: YEs i have it turned on checked in the back end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i got it to work in the end

```
    <?php $attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getTable_name();
 echo $attributeValue; ?>
```